# multiple activities error Android - Attempt to invoke virtual method ' ' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Fist of all, srry for my bad english.

I'm new in android and I'm creating a basic indoors map with mutiple activities connected without GPS or Internet, the first 9 activities went well, with all going good and smooth, but then i added the activity number 10 in the list, everything fine, no errors,  even when i debug the program, but when i tried to use the button to get to the last activity that I added, the app just stop working and in the run window this message came to me

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.erick.marriotmap/com.example.erick.marriotmap.m401_425}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

And if i try to put another activity connected to another button but being more than 9 activities in total this problem is always present.

The button is this:

```
<Button
            android:text="stairs"
            android:textSize="8dp"
            android:layout_width="57dp"
            android:layout_height="31dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn_stairs3"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0" />
```

and the code for the action is this:

```
bstairs3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent bstr3  = new Intent(m501_517.this, m401_425.class);
                startActivity(bstr3);
            }
        });
```

this is all the code for references

the class:

```
package com.example.erick.marriotmap;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class m501_517 extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button blobby;
    Button bstaira1;
    Button bstairs2;
    Button bstairs3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_m501_517);

        bstaira1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_stairs1);
        bstairs2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_stairs2);
        bstairs3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_stairs3);
        blobby = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_lobby);

        bstaira1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent bstr1  = new Intent(m501_517.this, m601_608.class);
                startActivity(bstr1);
            }
        });

        bstairs2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent bstr2  = new Intent(m501_517.this, m601_608.class);
                startActivity(bstr2);
            }
        });

        bstairs3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent bstr3  = new Intent(m501_517.this, m401_425.class);
                startActivity(bstr3);
            }
        });


        blobby.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent blobby  = new Intent(m501_517.this, mlobby_quinto.class);
                startActivity(blobby);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

The activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.erick.marriotmap.m501_517"
    android:background="@drawable/p601_608"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:baselineAligned="false">


    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/p501_517">

        <Button
            android:text="Stairs"
            android:textSize="8dp"
            android:layout_width="57dp"
            android:layout_height="31dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn_stairs2"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="235dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

        <Button
            android:text="stairs"
            android:textSize="8dp"
            android:layout_width="57dp"
            android:layout_height="31dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn_stairs3"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0" />

        <Button
            android:text="lobby"
            android:textSize="8dp"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn_lobby"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="215dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dp" />

        <Button
            android:text="stairs"
            android:textSize="8dp"
            android:layout_width="57dp"
            android:layout_height="31dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn_stairs1"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="230dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />
    </GridLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The button is supposed to go to this activity and class:

Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.erick.marriotmap.m401_425"
    android:background="@drawable/p401_425"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:baselineAligned="false">


    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.02">

        <Button
            android:text="stairs"
            android:textSize="8dp"
            android:layout_width="56dp"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn_str1"
            android:layout_weight="0.02"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp" />

        <Button
            android:text="stairs"
            android:textSize="8dp"
            android:layout_width="56dp"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn_str2"
            android:layout_weight="0.02"
            android:layout_marginLeft="120dp" />

        <Button
            android:text="stairs"
            android:textSize="8dp"
            android:layout_width="56dp"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn_str3"
            android:layout_weight="0.02"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="110dp" />

        <Button
            android:text="stairs"
            android:textSize="8dp"
            android:layout_width="56dp"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn_str5"
            android:layout_weight="0.02"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="120dp" />

        <Button
            android:text="Kids Club"
            android:textSize="8dp"
            android:layout_width="56dp"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn_kids"
            android:layout_weight="0.02"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="120dp" />

        <Button
            android:text="stairs"
            android:textSize="8dp"
            android:layout_width="56dp"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn_str4"
            android:layout_weight="0.02"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="130dp" />

    </GridLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Class:

```
package com.example.erick.marriotmap;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class m401_425 extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button bkids;
    Button bstairs1;
    Button bstairs2;
    Button bstairs3;
    Button bstairs4;
    Button bstairs5;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_m401_425);

        bstairs1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_str1);
        bstairs2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_str2);
        bstairs3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_str3);
        bstairs4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_str4);
        bstairs5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_str5);
        bkids = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_lobby);

        bstairs1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent bstr1  = new Intent(m401_425.this, m501_517.class);
                startActivity(bstr1);
            }
        });

        bstairs2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent bstr2  = new Intent(m401_425.this, m501_517.class);
                startActivity(bstr2);
            }
        });

        bstairs3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent bstr3  = new Intent(m401_425.this, m501_517.class);
                startActivity(bstr3);
            }
        });
        bstairs4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent bstr3  = new Intent(m401_425.this, m501_517.class);
                startActivity(bstr3);
            }
        });
        bstairs5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent bstr3  = new Intent(m401_425.this, m501_517.class);
                startActivity(bstr3);
            }
        });


        bkids.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent bkids  = new Intent(m401_425.this, map.class);
                startActivity(bkids);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

and this is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.erick.marriotmap">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:resizeableActivity="false" android:label="Sexto piso - Lobby" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name=".map"></activity>

        <activity android:resizeableActivity="false" android:label="Sexto piso - Habitaciones 601 - 608" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:name=".m601_608"></activity>
        <activity android:resizeableActivity="false" android:label="Sexto piso - Habitaciones 626 - 640" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:name=".m626_640"></activity>
        <activity android:resizeableActivity="false" android:label="Quinto piso - Lobby" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name=".mlobby_quinto"></activity>
        <activity android:resizeableActivity="false" android:label="Quinto piso - Habitaciones 526 - 549" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:name=".m526_549"></activity>
        <activity android:resizeableActivity="false" android:label="Septimo piso - Lobby" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:name=".mlobby_septimo"></activity>
        <activity android:resizeableActivity="false" android:label="Septimo piso - Habitaciones 726 - 733" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:name=".m726_733"></activity>
        <activity android:resizeableActivity="false"  android:label="Quinto piso - Habitaciones 501 - 517" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:name=".m501_517"></activity>

        <activity android:resizeableActivity="false"  android:label="Cuarto piso - Habitaciones 401 - 425" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:name=".m401_425"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I know this is a long post and I know there will be someone that will say that this question is already answered, but I couldn't find a good answer for my problem, please boys and girls I need your help

Comment: What is the name of the xml layout? Is it "activity_m401_425"?

Comment: The name of the xml with the button is activity_m501_517 and the layout target is activity_m401_425